# Show that any continuous function has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $a < b$ and $f: [a,b] \to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that the range of $f$ contains $[a,b]$. Prove that $f$ has a fixed point.

I did a similar proof where f contains the range of $f$ instead of the other way around. How to go about doing this one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function so that $f\{[a,b]\}\supset [a,b]$

define $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be such that $g(x)=f(x)-x$, we want to show that $g$ is zero in at least one point

Then there is $a'$ so that $f(a')=a$ and there is $b'$ so that $f(b')=b$

Suppose that $a'<b'$. Then consider the interval $[a',b']$. Notice $g(a')=a'-a\geq 0$ and $g(b')=b'-b\leq0$. SO by the intermediate value theorem there is an $x$ in $[a',b']$ so that $g(x)=0$ as desired.

if $a'>b'$ do the same thing with the interval $[b,a]$

Comment: for the one where the range is contained in [a,b] I did the following:
g(x)=f(x)-x
x=a : g(a)=f(a)-a>=0
x=b : g(b)=f(b)-b<=0
then by IVM, there exist some c such that g(c)=0 hence f(c)=c

Comment: Perfect, the same argument works on the second case.

Comment: The argument works the same regardless of which contains which?

Comment: Oh my, I made a mistake, Let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed, I'm so sorry, I had misread your question at first.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Think about the function $f(x)-x$. Can you find some value where this is guaranteed to be non-positive? Non-negative?